# Поменять язык программы

Tags: android

Обновил плагины, перезагрузил программу, после чего язык Android Studio перешёл на японский. Скажите пожалуйста как снова вернуть на английский?

Comment: Переустанови и не парся

Comment: переустанавливаю. всё равно язык остаётся китайским(японским)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29404523/12771929